# Shallow well pressure loss

Tags: water, well, shallow

I am experiencing loss of pressure with my pressure tank. More and more frequent I am losing water. The pressure gauge when I check it is zero. When up and working pressure switch seems to close at 4⁰ psi and open at 50 psi. All equipment approximately 5 yrs old. When pressure gauge is at zero, voltage is present, pressure switch is closed but without pressure so no water. Any help appreciated! At zero psi the pressure switch is closed.  If I kill the power for 30-60 minutes it all comes back.

Comment: Is the pump motor running at 0 pressure, or not? What do you do to reset it?

Comment: Turn off 30 mins

Comment: And the pump motor is running while at 0 PSI?

Comment: I think so . Haven't pulled well cap to look and don't have an amp meter. The pressure switch is certainly closed with voltage going to pump.

Comment: You said shallow well, but now it appears you are talking about a submersible pump down the well...?...?...?

Comment: Shallow well , concrete tube with cap ,40' deep, 20' of water. Stainless pump hangs on rope, submirsed in water. People in these parts call this a shallow well. Other types of wells in this area are 600'-800' deep.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this means there is some problem with building/holding pressure *or* there's an intermittent problem with the pressure switch itself.

One typical case is running the well dry - can't pump water that's not there.

If the pump motor shut off, the pressure switch may be of the "low  pressure cutout" variety that helps you not kill the pump when it can't make pressure, by shutting off below ~20PSI. If the pump motor is running at 0 PSI, you probably have pump damage already.

The adjustment of the pressure switch appears a bit non-standard - typically the differential is set to 20 PSI, so 40 PSI cut-in would go with 60 PSI cut out, or 50 PSI cut-out would go with 30 PSI cut in.

That 10 PSI differential can be OK, but usually requires a larger pressure tank to meet the standard recommendation that the pump should run for more than 60 seconds to go from cut-in to cut-out if no water is being used. Minimizing the number of pump starts is generally held to be beneficial to pump lifetime, so that's a minimum run-time recommendation - longer is fine, so long as the pressure does continue to rise. If the pressure plateaus and the pump keeps running, that's not good, and either means the pump is worn and needs rebuilt, or the draw (from the well level to the surface) is too great.

Another case is a leak in the intake pipe, causing loss of suction - but you didn't mention getting a lot of air out of the faucets.